# Word for who professes discrimination based on culture

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

A person that professes discrimination based on race is a racist.

What is the word for defining a person that discriminates based on culture (pretty sure it is not *culturist*) or social habits?

E.g., Eric Cartman doesn't like hippies, he discriminates against them. But a hippie is not a race, an ethnic, a religion or a nationality. It is a life style not related to any of these.

Comment: Clarification: Eric Cartman doesn't like _anyone_.

Comment: If I discriminated based on style, would that make me a _stylist_? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate or related: [Other word for discrimination based on demographic categories?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82736/other-word-for-discrimination-based-on-demographic-categories)

Comment: How about "classist"?

Answer (score 5):

Snob is probably the word you're looking for. A more precise, but less common word might be ethnocentrist. Other possibilities: elitist, jingoist.

[Snob](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snob) from Merriam-Webster: "one who tends to rebuff, avoid, or ignore those regarded as inferior"

[Ethnocentrist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ethnocentrist), the adjectival or *noun* form of [ethnocentrism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ethnocentrism) from the ODO: "Evaluation of other cultures according to preconceptions originating in the standards and customs of one's own culture."

[Elitist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/elitist) from the ODO: "A person who believes that a society or system should be led by an elite."

[Jingoist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jingoism) from Merriam-Webster: "extreme chauvinis[t] or nationalis[t] marked especially by a belligerent foreign policy."

Answer (score 3):

Also see "xenophobe".  Not quite on point (though, as with "homophobe", common usage implies animus more than literal fear), but maybe it fits the sentence you're trying to write.

Comment: These imply more nationalism than culturalism(?), but if you want an "-ist", also try chauvinist, jingoist.

Answer (score 2):

Generally this would just be called *cultural discrimination*. There are more specific words for some of the special cases:

- If it wasn't an isolated incident and someone makes a habit of doing this, particularly if they were vocal or opinionated about it, they might be called *judgmental*.
- If the opinions are particularly egregious violations of societal norms or border on more serious sorts of discrimination, the person might be called a *bigot*.
- If someone tends to disapprove of cultures that occupy a lower social status, they might be called a *snob*, especially if they themselves are a higher social status.
- If someone just doesn't like cultural norms other than their own in general, they might be called *insular* or *parochial*.

Comment: That third type of person you call a snob might be described as _classist_.

Answer (score 2):

A generalized word for a person who is intolerant of people different than themselves would be a *"bigot"* so someone who is intolerant of another culture could be called a *"cultural bigot"* and could be accused of *"cultural bigotry"*.

Merriam-Webster's definition of "[bigot](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?va=bigot)":

> "a person who won't listen to anyone whose ideas or beliefs are different from his or her own; especially : one who regards or treats the members of a group (as a racial group) with hatred and intolerance"

Answer (score 1):

Not perfectly discrimination, but you can take the word 'CHAUVINIST' in this regard, although it has more to do with one's superiority over other's country, sex, region rather that discrimination